# Android jtds MS SQL 2008r2 getconnection java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set

Tags: android, sql-server, connection, jtds

Please help!

I use jtds1.2.7.jar (1.2.5 to 1.2.8) to connect my SQL Server 2008R2 and it was working normally until I add new dependencies to gradle to compile (and it doesn't matter what kind of library). After I added some layouts and classes I get this error again... I didn't change my code, connection strings, queries or anything else.  I don't know what to do.

Here is my code:

```
class login extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> { 
    Integer mysession=0; 
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer i) { 
        Log.d("zxc","remember settings"); 
        super.onPostExecute(i); 
    } 
    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        login_try++; 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
    } 
    @Override 
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) { 
        MyApplication.MY_IP=MyApplication.getLocalIpAddress(); 
        try { 
            Connection conn = null; 
            try 
            { 
                 Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"); 


                Log.d("zxc", "MSSQL connected"); 

                Log.d("zxc", "MSSQL driver"); 
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(MyApplication.db_url, MyApplication.db_name, MyApplication.db_password  ); 



                Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
                Log.d("zxc", "good!"); 
                String query = "DECLARE @code int,@code_name varchar(150),@id_session int,@Questions_xml xml, @JK_array xml, @My_info xml, @My_avatar nvarchar(max)" + 
                        " EXEC    [DS_CRM].[dbo].[Autorization_Revizor]    @Login = N'" + MyApplication.MY_LOGIN + "', @Password = N'"+ MyApplication.MY_PASSWORD +"', @id_value_enter = 1, @IP = N'" + MyApplication.MY_IP +  "', @Useragent = N'" + MyApplication.SOFTWAREVERSION + "', @Comment = N'IMEI:" + MyApplication.MYIMEI +  "', @code = @code OUTPUT, @code_name = @code_name OUTPUT, @id_session = @id_session OUTPUT, @Questions_xml = @Questions_xml OUTPUT, @My_info = @My_info OUTPUT, @JK_array = @JK_array OUTPUT, @My_avatar=@My_avatar OUTPUT " + 
                        " SELECT    @code as N'code',@code_name as N'code_name', @id_session as N'id_session', @Questions_xml as N'Questions_xml', @My_info as N'My_info',   @JK_array as N'JK_array',   @My_avatar as N'My_avatar'"; 


            catch (java.sql.SQLException e)   {    e.printStackTrace(); 
                Log.d("zxc", "bad=" + e.toString()); resultcode="Не смог подключиться к БД"; } //HERE IS MY EXCEPTION!!!!!!!! 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {   e.printStackTrace();  resultcode="Не смог выполнить функцию запроса";  } 
        return mysession; 
    } 
}
```

and here is my exception:

```
:52.422 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 D/zxc: MSSQL connected
07-12 20:35:52.950 56-56/? D/Genymotion: Received Ping
07-12 20:35:53.054 15658-15659/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 701K, 15% free 10351K/12167K, paused 19ms+12ms, total 52ms
07-12 20:35:53.890 15658-15659/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 857K, 15% free 10945K/12871K, paused 13ms+37ms, total 177ms
07-12 20:35:54.950 56-56/? D/Genymotion: Received Ping
07-12 20:35:55.566 15658-15684/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
07-12 20:35:55.862 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set.
07-12 20:35:55.866 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:517)
07-12 20:35:55.874 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1433)
07-12 20:35:55.874 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:401)
07-12 20:35:55.886 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:188)
07-12 20:35:55.886 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
07-12 20:35:55.890 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:209)
07-12 20:35:55.894 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02.Screen_1$login.doInBackground(Screen_1.java:1072)
07-12 20:35:55.894 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02.Screen_1$login.doInBackground(Screen_1.java:1044)
07-12 20:35:55.906 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-12 20:35:55.934 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-12 20:35:55.946 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-12 20:35:55.966 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-12 20:35:55.966 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-12 20:35:55.978 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-12 20:35:55.994 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-12 20:35:55.994 15658-15763/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 D/zxc: bad=The executeQuery method must return a result set.
07-12 20:35:56.026 15658-15658/ru.ds_exp.test_07042016_02 D/zxc: remember settings
```

Comment: several times rebuild project, change jtds1.2.5 to jtds1.2.1 and everything is ok now... :)

Comment: add some code and same thing again!!!

Comment: with help of sql profiler found that with drivermanager.getconnection there is a select query to mssql ( Select @@maxprecision and some set queries). and it returns a row. and this row getconnection can't handle i think...